# Cannot run Apache2 server in ubuntu

Tags: linux, postgresql, apache, ubuntu, pgadmin-4

I've installed pgAdmin4 in Ubuntu 18.04 by doing:

$ curl https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub | sudo apt-key add

$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/$(lsb_release -cs) pgadmin4
main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list && apt update'

$ sudo apt install pgadmin4

$ sudo /usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh

After creating an account and before adding the Postgresql server in pgAdmin4 I got this message displayed:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHI6z.png

Since I was having problems with systemd, I've used Sysvinit system to start the apache2 by doing:

$ service apache2 start

outcome:

- Starting Apache httpd web server apache2                                                                                                                                                                         *
- The apache2 configtest failed.
  Output of config test was:
  mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/run/apache2': Permission denied
  chown: changing ownership of '/var/lock/apache2.Y3B3u6svcJ': Operation not permitted

not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run apache as root:

```
sudo service apache2 start
```